# How to get the value of html select option using python in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, html, forms, google-app-engine, select

I am working on a web application using Google App Engine. I am using Python Runtime Environment. I am also using Jinja2 framework. The problem I have is this: On my html page, I have the following markup inside a form:

```
 <select name="word" class="span4">
      <option value="authors" selected>Authors</option>
      <option value="blogs">Blogs</option>
      <option value="bloggers">Bloggers</option>
      <option value="ebooks">Ebooks</option>
      <option value="author">Author</option>
      <option value="writers">Writers</option>
      <option value="kindle">Kindle</option>
 </select>
```

Before switching to using `<select option>`, I was using `<input type="text"..../>` and getting the input value inside Python was as simple as :

```
def post(self):
    word = self.request.get('word')
```

but now I cannot get the script to work because I cannot access the selected value from the form submitted by the users. Please help because I have looked around and couldn't find anything clear!
Thank you and I look forward to your help!

Comment: And what happens when you use that code now?

Comment: i have the same problem - did you ever figure out?  looks like noone has been able to answer.

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
self.request.get_all('word')
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass?hl=en#Request_get_all