# Name the selected option in html

Tags: html, python-3.x

For the input boxes I am able to name each entry as ds and df. And I am able to pass this names to the python file as variables.

```
<html><title> Acqusition </title>
<body><h1> Acqusition </h1>
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/sil2.py">    
    id1: <input type="number" name="ds",min="1" max="100">
    id2: <input type="number" name="df",min="1" max="100">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to name the selected option and want to pass the value to the python file as a variable. how can I do it?

```
<html><title> rapor </title>
<body><h1> rapor </h1>
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/sil3.py">    
    <select>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: I found the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442717/how-to-get-the-value-of-html-select-option-using-python-in-google-app-engine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value of html select option using python in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442717/how-to-get-the-value-of-html-select-option-using-python-in-google-app-engine)